# Comparing Coefficients from Two Different Linear Models in R

Tags: r, modeling

I am currently using a variable selection technique that requires me to determine if the coefficient for any given variable changed by more than 20% between models with different combinations of variables. I tried:

```
abs(model1$coefficients - model2$coefficients)/model1$coefficients
```

but the vectors are not the same length (because there are different variables in each model) so they are not lined up properly. Is there a way to compare coefficients with the same variable name across models? I could do this by hand, but there are 50+ coefficients and 10 models so it would take forever.

Sorry if this is obvious, but I have not been able to figure it out. I have looked around for answers to point me in the right direction, but all of them have to do with statistical comparisons of coefficients and do not include code that helps me solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't give any sample data so I am going to simulate data based on a model `y = a + b * x1 + c * x2 + e`, where `e ~ N(0, 1)`.

I then fit two models: `y ~ x1` and `y ~ x1 + x2` and use a custom function `getEstimates` to extract parameters for the same predictor from both models. It's also a good idea to assess the importance of additional predictors using an ANOVA.

```
# Simulate some data
set.seed(2017);
generateData <- function(a = 1, b = 2, c = -2, nPoints = 1000) {
    x1 <- runif(nPoints);
    x2 <- runif(nPoints);
    y <- a + b * x1 + c * x2 + rnorm(nPoints);
    return(data.frame(y = y, x1 = x1, x2 = x2));
}
df <- generateData();


# Fit1: y ~ a + b * x1
fit1 <- lm(y ~ x1, data = df);

# Fit2: y ~ a + b * x1 + c * x2
fit2 <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2, data = df);

# ANOVA to explore importance of variable
anova(fit1, fit2);
#Analysis of Variance Table
#
#Model 1: y ~ x1
#Model 2: y ~ x1 + x2
#  Res.Df     RSS Df Sum of Sq     F    Pr(>F)
#1    998 1292.20
#2    997  994.46  1    297.74 298.5 < 2.2e-16 ***
#---
#Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

# Function to get estimates for parameter(s) par
# from two models fit1 and fit2
getEstimates <- function(par, fit1, fit2) {
    lst <- lapply(par, function(x)
        c(summary(fit1)$coef[x, 1], summary(fit2)$coef[x, 1]));
    names(lst) <- par;
    return(lst);
}

# Get coefficient for predictor x1
est <- getEstimates("x1", fit1, fit2);
```

Based on the output of `getEstimates` you can then calculate the relative change of a parameter between two models.

```
# Calculate relative change in estimated x1 coefficient from both models
lapply(est, function(x) abs(x[1] - x[2])/x[1]);
#$x1
#[1] 0.0282493
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I am getting this error when I try to run your function:     "Error in summary(fit1)$coef[x, 1] : subscript out of bounds". Do you know why this might be an issue? Also I am using the GLM function because it is a probit model, in case that changes anything.

Comment: @bbernicker It's a bit difficult to debug without any sample data. How did you call `getEstimates`? Can you  `dput` (part of) your source data (or alternatively provide sample data), and update your original question to include the `glm` calls for two different models. `getEstimates` still works for me when I use a generalised linear model.

Comment: @bbernicker PS. Obviously `getEstimates` will only work on predictor parameters that are present in both models. So in my example, `getEstimates("x2", fit1, fit2)` will throw an error because `fit1` does not contain `x2` as a model predictor. You could optimise `getEstimates` to do a safety check.